# Application.Wait does skip some commands

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

If I use the command "Application.Wait (1)" the programm skips the next command.
I am using Application.Wait inside a for-loop.

I am using this code:

```css
    For i = 1 To 34
        Application.Wait (2)
        Call Rechts
    Next i
```

This Code copy on each round a picture in a picture-box.
But actually the code copy only the last one in the picture box.
On the End it should looks like a slideshow.

How can I wait one second in a For-Loop?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the time that the application should wait *until*

The easiest way to do this is using the `Now()` method and adding your own additional variant like so:

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
```